# What exactly is the input of decoder in autoencoder setup

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoder

I am reviewing various autoencoder setups for MNIST reconstruction, Seq2Seq translation and others.
My naive understanding of data flow is as follows:

**Input -> [Encoder] -> Hidden Representation -> [Decoder] -> Output.**

[image]

However, in case of Seq2Seq translation task similar to [Sutskever et. al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.3215.pdf) decoder input is combined from hidden state + input sequence.

[image]

I wonder how is the input of decoder dependent on the target task? Why do we need to put input sequence besides the hidden state? Any high-level explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are mixing two different beasts. Despite both having encoder and decoder parts, the way in which a normal feedforward image transformation network (i.e. the autoencoder) and an autoregressive model (i.e. the seq2seq) are actually used is very different:

- In the type of image transformation done in a vanilla autoencoder, you input an image and get another image at the output. That's it, both at training and at inference time.
- In an autoregressive model like seq2seq, you feed the network with the input **and the initial tokens of the expected output sequence** (i.e. the prefix), and you get the next token as output. During training, those initial tokens are normally from the *gold data* (*aka* teacher forcing), that is, you feed as prefix real tokens from the training data. In inference, those tokens are generated by the model itself: you generate the first token, then you generate the second token given the first one you previously generated, then you generate the third token given the previous 2 generated tokens, and so on.